# Normalise a pandas column that may contain json text

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm looking to expand a column that contains json data into new columns in the existing dataframe. I think part of the challenge I'm facing is that not all rows in the dataframe contain an entry in the json column and not all key combinations within the json are known i.e. I can't define a list of column headers ahead of time.

This is what I've tried so far:

`df2 = pd.json_normalize(df1['additionalInfo'])`

I've seen the above command be suggested in other posts and work, and it does for simple datasets but when I apply it to my dataset I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'`

I have also tried extracting only the fields that I need from the json by using:

`df1['VCPUs'] = df1.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x['additionalInfo'])['VCPUs'], axis=1)`

Thew above only works when every row in the df contains a VCPUs field within the json held in the additionalInfo column and that is not the case in my dataset.

The dataset I'm using is an azure usage file which is several GB in size and has 55 columns.

Here is a sanitised sample extract of the AdditionalInfo column:

{  "AccountName": "pidabstest",  "PoolName": "series-pool",  "VMName": "dsdfasad",  "ConfigType": "VirtualMachine",  "NodeType": "Dedicated",  "PoolAllocationMode": "BatchService",  "UsageType": "DataTrIn",  "VCPUs": "0",  "UsageReceiveTime": "2020-06-04T00:52:01Z"}
NULL
NULL
{  "AccountName": "asfdasfsa",  "PoolName": "parallel-pool",  "VMName": "asdfasdfdsa",  "ConfigType": "VirtualMachine",  "NodeType": "Dedicated",  "PoolAllocationMode": "BatchService",  "ServiceType": "Standard_E4_v3",  "UsageType": "ComputeHR",  "VCPUs": "4",  "UsageReceiveTime": "2020-06-03T03:05:12Z"}
NULL
{  "UsageType": "DataTrIn",  "ImageType": null,  "ServiceType": null,  "VMName": null,  "VMProperties": null,  "VCPUs": 0,  "CPUs": 0}
NULL
NULL
NULL
{  "UsageType": "DataTrOut",  "ImageType": null,  "ServiceType": null,  "VMName": null,  "VMProperties": null,  "VCPUs": 0,  "CPUs": 0}
{  "vCores": 4,  "SLO": "SQLDB_GP_Gen4_4",  "UniqueResourceId": "dsafdasfsda",  "AHUB": "False"}
NULL
NULL
{  "UsageType": "DataTrOut",  "ImageType": null,  "ServiceType": null,  "VMName": null,  "VMProperties": null,  "VCPUs": 0,  "CPUs": 0}
{  "AccountName": "afdads",  "PoolName": "asdfasdfsdf",  "VMName": "dsafsdffsfsdafd",  "ConfigType": "VirtualMachine",  "NodeType": "Dedicated",  "PoolAllocationMode": "BatchService",  "UsageType": "loadBalancers",  "UsageReceiveTime": "2020-06-03T15:51:18Z"}
NULL
NULL
{  "UsageType": "ComputeHR",  "ImageType": null,  "ServiceType": "Standard_E8s_v3",  "VMName": null,  "VMProperties": null,  "VCPUs": 8,  "CPUs": 0}
NULL
NULL

There are 7 fields I need to convert into columns and ideally I would like to create columns for only those 7 fields but if this is not possible creating a column for every field found within the json column throughout the df is acceptable albeit less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This example will parse the non-empty columns with `json.loads` and then put the data inside to extra columns:

```py
import json

mask = df['additionalInfo'].notna()
df.loc[mask, 'additionalInfo'] = df.loc[mask, 'additionalInfo'].apply(json.loads)

df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('additionalInfo').apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('ai_')], axis=1)
df = df.fillna('')

print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| ai_AccountName | ai_PoolName | ai_VMName | ai_ConfigType | ai_NodeType | ai_PoolAllocationMode | ai_UsageType | ai_VCPUs | ai_UsageReceiveTime | ai_0 | ai_ServiceType | ai_ImageType | ai_VMProperties | ai_CPUs | ai_vCores | ai_SLO | ai_UniqueResourceId | ai_AHUB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pidabstest | series-pool | dsdfasad | VirtualMachine | Dedicated | BatchService | DataTrIn | 0 | 2020-06-04T00:52:01Z |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| asfdasfsa | parallel-pool | asdfasdfdsa | VirtualMachine | Dedicated | BatchService | ComputeHR | 4 | 2020-06-03T03:05:12Z |  | Standard_E4_v3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | DataTrIn | 0 |  |  |  |  |  | 0.0 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | DataTrOut | 0 |  |  |  |  |  | 0.0 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 4.0 | SQLDB_GP_Gen4_4 | dsafdasfsda | False |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | DataTrOut | 0 |  |  |  |  |  | 0.0 |  |  |  |  |
| afdads | asdfasdfsdf | dsafsdffsfsdafd | VirtualMachine | Dedicated | BatchService | loadBalancers |  | 2020-06-03T15:51:18Z |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | ComputeHR | 8 |  |  | Standard_E8s_v3 |  |  | 0.0 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |